# Validate column names and types of data in spark dataframe

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, validation, pyspark

I want to read .csv file using pyspark in python, but I want to give just type for each column and use header(from .csv file) for column names(not names in schema). Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always have to give column a name when defining a schema in Spark. But you can pass option [`inferSchema`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.csv) into `spark.read.csv` so Spark will pickup column name and infer data type automatically